# How can we make QTableWidget accessible from multiple threads and placing QPushButtons in a cell from another thread.?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, locking, qtablewidget

I am new in Qt.I have a QTableWidget which is suppose to get continuous data from different threads of RTI DDS subscriber.I was using setUpdatesEnabled() property of the QTableview for updating values from another class.

But it also blocks the QTableWidget for in-between operations like selecting another row  and whenever i try to add QPushButton in a certain column of QTableWidget with the help of setCellWidget(),it is making a separate PushButton instead of placing it inside that cell.

Comment: In most cases I would use signals and slots (with Qt::QueuedConnection) to add the items from the other threads. Much simpler that way.

Comment: @drescherjm The default automatic connection is sufficient.

Comment: Agreed. I was debating whether or not to mention that or not.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you should do no GUI update from anywhere but the main thread. So use a `signal`/`slot` connection to go back from a worker thread to the main thread and then do the GUI update (emit the `signal` from the worker thread and make sure the `slot` is being executed from the main thread, this should behave like this with default connection). Be careful to the lifetime of the variables passed to the emited `signal` if `slot` is executed through a `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Then, for your `QPushButton` not being in the cell. Make sure its parent is the `QTableWidget` upon creation (but I doubt this is really mandatory because I expect `QTableWidget` will make itself parent of the widget when `setCellWidget` is called).

It's hard to hep more with no code being posted in the OP.